# How can I change delay time by agent's state in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Im new on Anylogic and is building an Student Service simulation, in it I thought a senario that if student coming to service center with simple question, staff can solve that quickly, otherwise it takes staff more time. I use a statechart to implement the question type of student:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdsE.png)

and I set corrpesond delay time as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdsE.png)

Once I try to build, complier give me an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhOhi.png)

What does it mean? Can anyone tell me how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the short version of the if statement which returns a value
if(condition) else  DOESNT return anything

instead use this:

```
agent.inState(agent.simpleQuestion) ? triangular(1,2,3) : triangular(3,4,5)
```

or instead you could do the same but you should create a function and add the function to the time delay

```
timeDelay(agent)
```

and in the function you would do

```
if(agent.inState(agent.simpleQuestion))
return triangular(1,2,3);
else
return triangular(3,4,5);
```

Comment: The function method seems eaiser to understand. Thanks!